# Parse a file in R

Tags: r, parsing

I need to parse a file in R which looks like below:

```
Acc1    "product"="A","product"="B","product"="C"
Acc2    "product"="C","product"="D"
```

Above is a txt file and there is tab between Acc1 and "product".

The output should look like:

```
Column1 Column2
Acc1    A
Acc1    B
Acc1    C
Acc2    C
Acc2    D
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Mili, please do not post images of data. I suggest you revert to [my previous edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52959316/2). Some reasons (images of code/data) are immediate: I cannot copy code or data from your image into my R console and try it out, and I choose to not transcribe it manually. Some reasons are slightly less obvious but still important, including: it breaks screen readers *hard*; search engines don't read them, so searches will not find it; mobile device screen size might be a limiting factor. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272

Comment: Done, sorry about that. The alignment was messing up hence I posted an image.

Comment: Please read [Why is "can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4996248) (and putting in "please" doen't make it one, although it does make it more pleasant).

Comment: It might help to glance at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, the fact that code and data can be fixed-width with the simple press of `Ctrl-K` is a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest you look at a tidyverse solution for this. It can certainly be handled with base-R and `data.table` (as others might suggest in comments or answers), but this is a good start.

First, faking the data.

```
txt <- readLines(textConnection('Acc1    "product"="A A","product"="B","product"="C"
Acc2    "product"="C","product"="D"'))
```

In your case, you'd probably just do `readLines(filename)`.

This next block splits the "Acc" stuff from the rest.

```
txtsplit <- strsplit(gsub("^(\\S+)\\s+", "\\1|", txt), "\\|")
```

And finally, the rest of the processing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data_frame(
  Col1 = sapply(txtsplit, `[[`, 1),
  Col2 = sapply(txtsplit, `[[`, 2)
) %>%
  mutate(
    Col2 = gsub('"product"=', '', Col2),
    Col2 = strsplit(Col2, ",")
  ) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(
    Col2 = gsub('"', '', Col2)
  )
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   Col1  Col2 
#   <chr> <chr>
# 1 Acc1  A A
# 2 Acc1  B    
# 3 Acc1  C    
# 4 Acc2  C    
# 5 Acc2  D
```

There are several good tutorials on using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, a quick search will find better/newer than I can post here.

BTW: I separated removal of the quotes into a separate `mutate`, but it could easily have been handled in the initial `gsub`. I chose to keep it separate in case you had more than just single letters in the quotes, where removing them might cause parsing problems later.

Comment: I tried the above code and it works fine for the test data i gave above. My data actually has the product names in double quotes with space between them
eg: "product"="test A", "product"="test B" and each Acc has these products in multiple line. So something like this:

'Acc1    "product"="test A","product"="test B","product"="test C", "product"="test D","product"="test CE" 
'Acc2' "product"="test S","product"="test X","product"="test C", "product"="test Y","product"="test F" 

So when I run the above code, I get only first word of the product parsed

Comment: GIGO, unfortunately. Please update your OP with the more representative data.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a space in one of the products. The use of the pipe (`|`) was arbitrary, choose something that you "guarantee" does not occur in the data. Semi-colons or colons often work.

Comment: You can play with replacing the spaces with a comma and using `read.csv(text=txtsplit, header=FALSE)`, but depending on the rest of the data, it may not like the arbitrary number of columns ...